# WordPress Meta Query for two custom fields.

Tags: php, wordpress, search, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have custom post type named carrier in which there are two custom fields like age_min and age_max
let's say age_min value is 25 and age_max value is 90 and that is different on every post.

Now on the front end, there is one field for input to search. when the user types 65 and search then this number 65 should be searched in this range 25-90(vary on each post)

here is my code:

```
array
(
    'key'       => 'age_min',
    'value'     => $_POST['age'],
    'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
    'compare'   => '>='
),
array
(
    'key'       => 'age_max',
    'value'     => 90,
    'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
    'compare'   => '<='
)
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your operators around the wrong way. They should be read like:

KEY OPERATOR VALUE

The logic should be:

(age_min <= age) AND (age_max >= age)

For example:

(25 <= 65) AND (90 >= 65)

The query would look like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'carrier',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'age_min',
            'value'   => $_POST['age'],
            'compare'   => '<=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'age_max',
            'value'   => $_POST['age'],
            'compare' => '>=',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome - glad to help! Would you please up vote and accept my solution? Your votes and feedback are very helpful. Have a great day :)